# Question about math terminology: $n$-involutory functions?

Tags: terminology

I want to define a function $f$ to be "$n$-involutory" if it satisfies
$$f(f(f\dots(x)))\dots=f^n(x)=x $$
where there does not exist $k$ such that $1 \leq k < n$ where $f^k(x) = x$. In general, is it *acceptable* to invent terms as long as I define them properly? (I'm still working on the definition for $n$-involutory, but I'm pretty sure this suffices for my question)

I've been looking around for a while around SE but I'm still relatively confused about it. Sorry if my question doesn't really belong on here :c

Comment: Did you mean $1≤k<n$?  In any case:  as long as the term does not have a generally accepted definition already, it's perfectly reasonable to introduce a definition.  Just make sure your definition is clear and complete.

Comment: fixed it!! thanks for pointing it out.
also, what would you consider a clear and complete definition? I'm still in high school so are there specific things I should consider while writing these?

Comment: Worth remarking:  generally speaking, an "involutory function" is one that satisifes $f\circ f(x)=x$.  That would include the identity function while your notion of $2-$involutory would exclude the identity.  That's ok, though I would point things like that out along with the definition.

Comment: alright! I saw the wikipedia article on an "involutory function" so I wanted to generalize it a little :)

Comment: I think what you wrote was clear (now that you fixed the typo).  As I say, I'd  point out that your notion doesn't exactly match words in standard use, as the standard terms tend not to be concerned with the minimal "involutory" order.

Comment: alright - thank you!

Comment: Minor technical note:  as it stands, your definition is not clear when $n=1$ (as $1≤k<1$ isn't what you want).  As the only $1-$involutory function is the identity, you might want to declare that one as a special case.

Comment: okie. stack exchange is telling me to avoid discussions in comments so I'll head off for now, but thank you so much for your notes!

Comment: Isn't this notion just the notion of finite order in groups? In this case, the group of bijections of a set.

Comment: huh? Can you explain?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)